# linestring created from coordinates POSTGIS

Tags: database, postgresql, postgis

Can someone help ?

Here is the part of my code (sql) which doesn't work :

```
SELECT ST_LENGTH(geom) into distance FROM
     SELECT ST_GeographyFromText('srid=4326;linestring(lon_bus lat_bus, lon_stop lat_stop)') AS geom)
     AS dis;
```

`lon_bus`, `lat_bus`, `lon_stop` and `lat_stop` are coordinates I get from my database. When I try this, I have an error of parsing. But when I replace these variable by numeric, it works. Can someone help me on it? I would like to keep these variables in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work because the WKT with variables is invalid. Remember, [WKT is just regular text](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text), so don't confuse WKT with SQL.

You can [make a LineString](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_MakeLine.html) from two point geometries, then cast it to `::geography`.

```
SELECT ST_MakeLine(ST_MakePoint(lon_bus, lat_bus),
                   ST_MakePoint(lon_stop, lat_stop))::geography AS geog
FROM (
  SELECT 1 AS lon_bus, 2 AS lat_bus, 3 AS lon_stop, 4 AS lat_stop
) AS data;
```

To get the geodesic length, use ST_Length on the geography.

---

Based on the usage, the question isn't about how to make a linestring, but how to calculated the distance between two geographic positions. There are several ways to do this:

```
SELECT
  ST_Distance(bus, stop) AS cartesian_distance,
  ST_Distance_Sphere(bus, stop) AS sphere_distance,
  ST_Distance(bus::geography, stop::geography) AS geography_distance,
  ST_Length(ST_MakeLine(bus, stop)::geography) AS geography_length
FROM (
  SELECT ST_MakePoint(lon_bus, lat_bus) AS bus, ST_MakePoint(lon_stop, lat_stop) AS stop
  FROM (SELECT 1 AS lon_bus, 2 AS lat_bus, 3 AS lon_stop, 4 AS lat_stop) AS data
) AS data;
-[ RECORD 1 ]------+-----------------
cartesian_distance | 2.82842712474619
sphere_distance    | 314283.687770102
geography_distance | 313588.397192902
geography_length   | 313588.397192902
```

The last two get the same result. If you don't need the linestring (e.g. to draw on a map), then the simplest method is used for `geography_distance`.

Comment: thank you ! yeah, yesterday i found an alternative to it, as this :

Comment: SELECT ST_MAKELINE(ST_MAKEPOINT(lat_bus,lon_bus),ST_MAKEPOINT(lat_stop,lon_stop)) into linestring;

 -- distance (in m)
 SELECT ST_LENGTH(linestring)*100000 into distance;

Comment: the thing is, the values between this method and the first one i present are not the same (difference of 100 meters) ... anyway, thank you a lot !!!

Comment: @Navy07 100 m error is wayyy too much. The SQL in your comment is problematic for three reasons (1) axis order (lat, lon) needs to be corrected to (lon, lat), (2) cast the geometry to `::geography`, otherwise a Cartesian length is assumed, (3) don't multiply by 100000 (where did this come from)? See updates in answer to get the distance between the two points.

Comment: okay i'm gonna check this. Thank you very much for your implication ! be right back for the feedback ;)

Comment: have i ever told u that u were a genious ?!!! anyway, thank you very much !!! it works as u said ^^ yeah, i've been working on how getting a distance between two positions for two weeks (i'm new) ... so thank you !!!